# How many times larger is $ 8.19\cdot10^{-14} $ than $10^{-19} $

Tags: exponentiation

I'm reading in a book:

> While the rest energy contained in an electron, $ 8.19\cdot10^{-14} J $,
>   may seem ridiculously small, on the atomic scale it is tremendous.
>   Compare our answer to $10^{-19} J $, the energy gained or lost by a single
>   atom during a typical chemical reaction. The rest energy of an
>   electron is about 1,000,000 times larger!

I think the numbers are so small that I'm having trouble having an intuitive understanding of it the part *"1,000,000 times larger"*. Isn't 100,000 times larger a closer answer?

$$ 10^{-19} \cdot 10^{5} = 10^{-14} < 8.19\cdot10^{-14} $$

Comment: I guess they are rounding $8.19$ to $10$.

Comment: Your number is approx $\approx 10^{-13}$, which is about $10^6$ times larger than $10^{-19}$

Comment: The rest energy is 819,000 times as large as the typical chemical reaction energy, and 819,000 is almost a million.

Comment: $\dfrac{8\cdot19\cdot10^{-14}}{10^{-19}}=\dfrac{8\cdot19\cdot10^{-14}}{10^{-14}\cdot10^{-5}}$. Do you get $8\cdot19\cdot10^5$

Comment: This does not seem to be a question about maths. It is more like a quibble,